# Varnish transforming POST to GET

Tags: varnish

All the POST requests coming to Varnish are sent to the backend as GET. As a consequence I'm receiving 503 Bad gateway on all POST requests. GET requests are working just fine.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that I had a `return (lookup)` in my `vcl_recv` method. As Varnish cannot cache POST requests, it was transforming them to GET. Adding

```
if (req.request == "POST") {
    return (pass);
}
```

resp. for varnish 4

```
if (req.method == "POST") {
    return (pass);
}
```

did the trick and everything worked fine.

Comment: I've further seen cases where it has to be return(pipe).